# Counter not updating in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function that will take a variable then check to see if that variable is in localStorage, and if it's not, add it to localStorage. If it is in localStorage, it appends a number to the end, so that a new localStorage key gets added.

So far, I've gotten this far:

```
var title = "Test";
test(title);

function test(title) {
    counter = 0;
    console.log("counter = " + counter);
    if (localStorage.getItem(title)) {
        counter = counter + 1;
        title = title + " " + counter;
        console.log("found " + title);
        console.log("found " + counter);
        test(title);
    } else {
        console.log("not found " + title);
        console.log("not found " + counter);
        localStorage.setItem(title, " ");
        load();
    }
}

function load() {
    for (var key in localStorage) {
        $(".keys").append(key + "<br />");
    }
}
```

That way, when I run the function say 5 times, I should have localStorage keys for:

```
Test, Test 1, Test 2, Test 3, Test 4
```

Instead, I have localStorage keys for

```
Test, Test 1, Test 1 1, Test 1 1 1, Test 1 1 1 1
```

I'm not sure why the numbers aren't adding, but here's a jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/x6ALG/5/

Comment: It's a string, so you are not adding but concatenating. Use `parseInt` before adding

Comment: `counter` is not a string. It should be a number object, since I'm only adding `1` to the previous number, which is a number object, `0`.

Comment: You set `counter` to 0 at the beginning of the function, so it's reset every time you call `test()`.

Comment: Wouldn't `counter = counter + 1;` set it to `1` the first time, then the next time I call `test()`, `counter` would be `1`?

Comment: Yes, in fact the title is wrong, counter *is* being updated, but not in the way you expect. Use `parseInt(counter,10)` when doing the sum

Comment: So `counter = parseInt(counter,10) + 1;`? That doesn't work either.

Comment: I think it would work if you just moved `var counter = 0` to the start of the script outside the function. Also, if `title = title + " " + counter`, you're appending a space and the counter number to the existing title, so if `title` is "Test 1" and `counter` is 2, you'll get `"Test 1" + " " + 2 == "Test 1 2"`.

Comment: can you use cookies ???

Comment: @MarwanDoumit No, I cannot.

Comment: @Juhana Could you provide an example in the answers? If I move the `var counter = 0` to outside the function, my if statement fails to find the `counter` variable.

Comment: @Charlie - change "outside" to "before", and put ";" after "0".

Comment: You probably didn't move it far enough (it has to be defined before you call the `test()` function).

Comment: @Juhana That was my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the counter to outside the function so that you don't reset it to zero each time you call the function, and keep the `title` parameter clean so that you can perform arithmetic with the counter.

```
var counter = 0;
var title = "Test";

test(title);

function test(title) {
    var newTitle = title + " " + counter;
    console.log("counter = " + counter);
    if (localStorage.getItem( newTitle )) {

        counter = counter + 1;

        console.log("found " + newTitle);
        console.log("found " + counter);

        test(title);
    } else {

        console.log("not found " + newTitle);
        console.log("not found " + counter);
        localStorage.setItem( newTitle, " " );
        load();
    }
}

function load() {
    for (var key in localStorage) {
        $(".keys").append(key + "<br />");
    }
}
```

Note the `newTitle` variable.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x6ALG/7/

Comment: Although, is there anyway for it to not add a number to the original? So that it goes `Test, Test 1, Test 2`... etc?

Comment: `var newTitle = title; if( counter > 0 ) newTitle += " " + counter;`

Comment: Perfect, here's a complete jsFiddle if anyone wants it: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/x6ALG/10/

Answer (score 0):

Dont initialize the counter to 0 inside your function test. Make it global and intialize it outside the function. Every time your function is called, it starts the count from 0.

Comment: Could you provide an example.